# How do I find the surface area of a surface of revolution around a non zero axis of rotation?

Tags: calculus

In class I learned that the formula for the surface area of a surface area of revolution only works if the shape is made by rotating around either the x axis or the y axis. However, I have a problem which requires me to rotate around a non zero axis.

Please see this image for the problem. I'm not asking for the answer, but I don't even know where to start because I don't know how to even do a surface area of revolution around a non zero axis problem. (I have never seen one before either in homework or in class.)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6PXJ.jpg]

Comment: You do a change of variables, so that one of the variables is along the axis of rotation, the other one perpendicular.

Comment: In class my professor specifically told me that the integral should be in terms of one variable only. She said to imagine having a measuring tape that only has one variable on it. We haven't learned integrals with multiple different variables and stuff like that yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rotating about the line $y=-3$ then the radius of rotation is $f(x) +3$.  If you're rotating about the line $y=2$, then the radius of rotation is $f(x)-2$.

Comment: I am rotating around y = +3.